# QTableWidgetItem is getting itmes method not working

Tags: python, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am not able to populate this table, I do not knoe what I'm doing wrong, I have been reading some posts, and seems like everything is correct...however, nothing is appearing in my table.

Here is my code:

The totalProcess list is like that totalProcess = [ [list1],[list2],[list3]...]

```
def updateTable(self,totalProcess):

   for x in xrange(10):
       for i in xrange(len(totalProcess[x])):

           item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(totalProcess[x][i])
           self.ui.tableWidgetResults.setItem(x,i,item)
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have QTableWidget's [rowCount](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#rowCount-prop) and [columnCount](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop) attributes been set? QTableWidget will only display items within them. Otherwise the code is correct.

*PS*: There is no need to loop through the indices as in some other languages; you can use `for x in list` to iterate through the element of the list (`x` will be the element of the list).

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes the row and col attribs have been set, however the table is not "updating" with nex rows as desired after each iteration of the loop.....

Comment: @user2919052 I used your code to add items to a QTableWidget and it works. Can you provide a [short, reproducible](http://sscce.org/) example which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: It is fixed now, sorry, you were right, the col and row attribs were not right, now seems like it is working but maybe im getting some empty cells in between, I will have to take a look at it. I have another doubt....is it possible to make the tablr grow on each iteration???, I mean, what if the columns num is fixed but the rows num can not be fixed at the beginning? is it possible to "update" it and make the table grow? maybe using .repaint() method?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to have a varying number of columns for each row or a varying number of rows for each column. However, one can set rowCount to a higher value than the maximum row position used; the positions without any item are empty.

Comment: No no, maybe I didnt explain in good way, I mean, let's say that we know the number os columns, 10, from the beginning to the end, but we dont know the number of rows, like in an acquisition system, we just keep on adding new rows until the acquisition is finished. Would it be possible?

Comment: @user2919052 You could simply insert setRowCount() calls to expand the row count in the `for` loop. Better, you could let the for loop finish and then use `setRowCount(i+1)` (`i` is the position of the element and one is added as the positions are zero-indexed).

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, let's say that we know the number os columns, 10, from the
>   beginning to the end, but we dont know the number of rows, like in an
>   acquisition system, we just keep on adding new rows until the
>   acquisition is finished. Would it be possible?

Yes, it is possible, and it's very simple. For example you could do that like this:

```
 def AddRowToTable(self, list):                      # list is one of those from your totalProcess = [ [list1],[list2],[list3]...]
    row = self.ui.tableWidgetResults.rowCount()      # get current number of rows
    self.ui.tableWidgetResults.insertRow(row)        # insert new row
    for col in range(0, len(list)):                  # add items into row
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(QtCore.QString(unicode(list[col])))
        self.ui.tableWidgetResults.setItem(row, col, item)
```

> now seems like it is working but maybe im getting some empty cells in
>   between

that's why I've added `list[col]` into this `QtCore.QString(unicode(list[col]))` - to ensure it is valid value type for `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` input parametar.

Now you can simply iterate through `totalProcess` and for every `list` in it call `AddRowToTable`. PS Don't forget to `setColumnCount` before everythng.

Comment: You might want to use "for col, value in enumerate(list):" that way you already have the value as list[col] and col as the index, so you don't need to call list[col].

Comment: Sure, why not... although I don't think it'll give performance boost